# PowerBI Building a Dynamic Legend

Tags: dynamic, powerbi

I am attempting to create a dynamic visualization similar to what has been shown [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Dynamically-change-the-information-within-a-visual-via-a-slicer/ba-p/87027)

The example above allows you to use a slicer to select a metric/KPI, such as sales or costs, and display it as a value in a graph. However, what I am attempting to do is to select a *measure*, such as product or country, and display it as an axis or legend in a graph.

The above has you create a table with your measures, and then a formula laid out as such:

```
`Formula= SWITCH(TRUE(),
VALUES('Measure'[Measure]) = "Product", 'Data'[Product],
VALUES('Measure'[Measure]) = "Country", 'Data'[Country],
VALUES('Measure'[Measure]) = "Salesman", 'Data'[Salesman],
BLANK())`
```

However, this returns the error "a table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected". I never got this error when using the formula as the original post intended, but another post suggests to change the formula to:

```
`Formula = SWITCH(TRUE(),
FIRSTNONBLANK('Measure'[Measure],1) = "Product", 'Data'[Product],
FIRSTNONBLANK('Measure'[Measure],1) = "Country", 'Data'[Country],
FIRSTNONBLANK('Measure'[Measure],1) = "Salesman", 'Data'[Salesman],
BLANK())`
```

However, this formula, when applied as a row or legend in a graph, only ever seems to return the "Country" measure. My guess is because the table is sorted alphabetically and "Country" will always be the "FIRSTNONBLANK" value, despite any filter/slicer that I apply to the measure table I created.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring at this point `VALUES('Measure'[Measure]) = "Product"`.

The cause is just described in the message itself:

> a table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected

When 'Measure'[Measure] is not selected to a single value on the slicer, it cannot determine the value of 'Measure'[Measure] to compare with the literal string "Product".

To address this issue, you can first use `HASONEVALUE` to check if 'Measure'[Measure] has only one value in the current filter context.

```
Formula = 
IF( HASONEVALUE( 'Measure'[Measure] ),
    SWITCH(
        VALUES( 'Measure'[Measure] ),
        "Product", [Product],
        "Country", [Country],
        "Salesman", [Salesman]
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi Kosuke,

Thank you so much for your response, truly appreciated. However, when I apply this new field to the rows of my chart, it simply shows a single row with a blank header, as opposed to a new row for each category within either Product/Country/Salesman.

The 'Measure'[Measure} field is being filtered on a single selection, so I am not sure what I might be doing wrong. Any thoughts?

Thank you again!

Comment: @JesseU, I'm not sure what kind of visualization you are using, but it sounds you are selecting one value of 'Measure'[Measure] on a slicer, and only the value for the selected category appears in another visualization. That is indeed a very natural behavior. What if not using a slicer and put 'Measure'[Measure] into axis (or row or whatever depending on the type of visualization)  instead? By doing this, each column/cell/etc. in the visualization will have only one category of 'Measure'[Measure] in its filter context.

Comment: Hi Kosuke,

I am using a matrix visualization, with the goal of having the row headers populated by one of three different fields (Product/Country/Salesman), which would switch between the three fields by use of a slicer, in this case based off of the 'measure'[measure] field from a separate table.

As such, when the slicer on 'measure'[measure]  is set to country, the rows would populate as:
Canada
USA
Mexico

And when the  'measure'[measure] is set to Product, the rows would populate as:
Product 1
Product 2
Product 3

As such, I don't think that would work in this case

Comment: @JesseU thank you for sharing that. In that case, the approach will be totally different. You will need to put together all products, countries, and sales persons vertically in one [generic dimension table](https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/abstract-generic-dimension/), along with "Kind" column to indicate whether the row is a "product", or a "country", etc. Then the Measure slicer will slice this dimension table rather than the fact. I may show how to, but this technique is not recommended in general.